# Android: How to implement quiz app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement an Android app which includes a part where user can do a **quiz**. Since I'm kinda new to Android app development, I would like some advice on how to implement the quiz part, in terms of *layout*

I have a set of questions and each has their own respective choice of answers from which I retrieve from my API.

What is the **best** and **easy to implement** approach to do this? **I need to display each question page by page (Q1 -> Q2 -> ...).**

Do I generate a set of Fragments? Or do I somehow use RecyclerView to generate each page for each question?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of a broad question, but here are some quick ideas to get you started.

Off the top of my head, you could have an activity called QuestionActivity (or whatever you want), which would be the main container to display questions. You would then have a QuestionFragment which would be displayed inside the QuestionActivity. Each time you want to display a new question, you would call the Fragment's newInstance() method, passing in the appropriate data in a Bundle each time to populate the layout of the Fragment, then replacing the Fragment in the Activity using a fragment transaction.

As for the Fragment itself, you could maybe do a LinearLayout, with a TextView at the top to display the question, a set of RadioButtons below that, to show some multiple choice options, then a submit Button under that, which the user would use to submit his answer. Then of course you would receive all the click events for these things to determine which answer was selected, etc.

Your QuestionFragment layout might start with something like this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.david.timedtask.QuizActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/quiz_question"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option_one"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option_two"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option_three"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option_four"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submit_button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this would produce a result looking something like this...

[image]

Of course this is all pretty basic, but again, your question was pretty broad. There are plenty of docs available to show you how to actually code all this stuff and put it all together, but hopefully this will get you started.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of view do you use to show first quiz question but every next question should be shown in same view by changing values of current controls.